# Read from the standard input a natural number, n. Find the greatest perfect square that is less than or equal to n

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, n, maxi = 0;
  printf("\n Introduce the number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
  {
    i = 0;
    while (i < j) {
      i++;

      if (j == i * i) {
        if (j > maxi) {
          maxi = j;
          printf("%d", maxi);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have to find the greatest perfect square smaller than than a number `n`, I succeeded in finding all the perfect squares that are smaller than the number `n` but because each time it finds a perfect square it displays it I couldn't think of any way to compare all the perfect square that were found (or at least that's what I think the problem is) so I would appreciate some help.  I already know that you could also solve this problem using a more simpler method ( like the one below ) and if you have any other ideas on how to solve it I'd like to hear them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int n,j;
  printf("\n Your number:\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  j=(int)sqrt(n);
  printf("%d",j*j);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Move `printf("%d",maxi);` to after the `for` loop?

Comment: You could do an integer-arithmetic Newton-Raphson approximation: X(n+1) = (X(n) + X / X(n)) / 2; and see whether that gets there quicker than simply iterating over 1..N.  If your numbers are larger (say one million or more), that should outperform iteration.  For smaller numbers (say 100 or less), there may not be any advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You only need a single loop here.  Check if `i*i <= n`.  If so, set `maxi` to `i*i` and increment `i`:

```
int n, i = 1, sq = 1;

printf("\n Introduce the number:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

while (i*i <= n) {
    sq = i*i;
    i++;
}

printf("sq=%d\n", sq);
```

Comment: 2 corner problems.  When `n` is near `INT_MAX`, `i*i` overflows and is UB, which can be an infinite loop in this case.  With `n==0`, this reports `1`.

Answer (score 1):

> Find the greatest perfect square that is less than or equal to n

For `n>=0`, this is akin to finding the *integer* square root of `n`.

```
unsigned greatest_perfect_square(unsigned x) {
  unsigned root = usqrt(x);
  return root * root;
}
```

---

> if you have any other ideas on how to solve it I'd like to hear them.

The order of complexity to find the square root is O(bit-width-of-type-n).  e.g. 16 iterations.

```
#include <limits.h>
unsigned usqrt(unsigned x) {
  unsigned y = 0;
  unsigned xShifted = 0;

  const unsigned MSBit = UINT_MAX - UINT_MAX/2;
  // This  constant relies on no padding and bit width even
  const unsigned TwoBitCount_N = sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT / 2;
  for (unsigned TwoBitCount = TwoBitCount_N; TwoBitCount > 0; TwoBitCount--) {
    // Shift `xShifted` 2 places left while shifting in the 2 MSbits of x
    xShifted <<= 1;
    if (x & MSBit) {
      xShifted |= 1;
    }
    x <<= 1;
    xShifted <<= 1;
    if (x & MSBit) {
      xShifted |= 1;
    }
    x <<= 1;
    // Shift the answer 1 bit left
    y <<= 1;
    // Form test value as y*2 + 1
    unsigned Test = (y << 1) | 1;
    // If xShifted big enough ...
    if (xShifted >= Test) {
      xShifted -= Test;
      // Increment answer
      y |= 1;
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

---

OP's method is far far slower.  Even the inner loop takes O(sqrt(n)) time.

Note:
OP's code: `j == i * i` is subject to overflow and leads to the incorrect answer when `j` is larger.
`j/i == i` performs a like test without overflow.

---

[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977256/read-from-the-standard-input-a-natural-number-n-find-the-greatest-perfect-squa/52978394#comment92862550_52977256) suggested a [Newton-Raphson approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) approach.  Some lightly tested code below works quite fast, often taking only a few iterations.
I suspect this is `O(log(bit-width-of-type-n))` for the main part, yet of course still `O(log(bit-width-of-type-n))` for `bit_width()`.
Both of the functions could be improved.

```
unsigned bit_width(unsigned x) {
  unsigned width = 0;
  while (x) {
    x /= 2;
    width++;
  }
  return width;
}

unsigned usqrt_NR(unsigned x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  unsigned y = 1u << bit_width(x)/2;
  unsigned y_previous;
  unsigned diff;
  unsigned diff1count = 0;;
  do {
    y_previous = y;
    y = (y + x/y)/2;
    diff = y_previous < y ? y - y_previous : y_previous - y;
    if (diff == 1) diff1count++;
  } while (diff > 1 || (diff == 1 && diff1count <= 1));
  y = (y_previous + y)/2;
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This minimizes the number of multiplications: it looks for the first square which is larger than n, meaning that the perfect square immediately before was the solution.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i*i > n) {
        break;
    }
}
i--;
// i*i is your answer
```

On some platforms it might be useful to exploit the fact that `(i+1)*(i+1) = i*i + 2*i + 1`, or in other words, if you already have i^2, (i+1)^2 is obtained by adding i to it twice, and incrementing by 1; and at the beginning, 0^2 is 0 to prime the cycle.

```
for (i = 0, sq = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sq += i; // Or on some platforms sq += i<<1 instead of two sums
    sq += i; // Some compilers will auto-optimize "sq += 2*i" for the platform
    sq++;    // Or even sq += ((2*i)|1) as adding 1 to even numbers is OR'ing 1
    if (sq > n) {
        break;
    }
    // if sq is declared as signed integer, a possible overflow will
    // show it as being negative. This way we can still get a "correct" result
    // with i the smallest root that does not overflow.
    // In 16-bit arithmetic this is 181, root of 32761; next square would be
    // 33124 which cannot be represented in signed 16-bit space.
    if (sq < 0) {
        break;
    }
}
// (i*i) is your answer
```

Comment: Minor corner: When `n` is near `INT_MAX`, `int` math overflows --> UB.

Comment: Good catch; I've added a check of sorts.

Comment: I use to think as "possible overflow will show it as being negative" - yet found that [not robust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/simpler-method-to-detect-int-overflow).

Comment: I _think_ `for (i = 0, sq = 0; 2*i < n - sq; i++) {
    sq += 2*i + 1; } // sq is your answer;` will work (no OF) using your nifty exploit.